# Unexpected Output When Iterating Over List of Dictionaries - Python & Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, rest, dictionary, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to iterate over a list of dictionaries from a JSON file that was pulled from Microsoft Graph. The code that I am using is able to store the lists in a variable, but instead of getting the expected 9 items  I am getting 27.

My code is:

```
for i in range(len(json_data_list)):
    try:
        for key in json_data_list[i]:
            headers.append(json_data_list[i]['internetMessageHeaders'])
    except KeyError:
        continue
    i += 1
```

Here's an example of the JSON data:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#users('48d31887-5fad-4d73-a9f5-3c356e68a038')/messages(internetMessageHeaders)",
"@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages?$select=internetMessageHeaders&$skip=12",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e/T7KzowPTAAEMTBu8\"",
        "id": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAEMOXaXAAA="
    },
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e/T7KzowPTAAEMTBuN\"",
        "id": "AAMkAGVmMDEzMTM4LTZmYWUtNDdkNC1hMDZiLTU1OGY5OTZhYmY4OABGAAAAAAAiQ8W967B7TKBjgx9rVEURBwAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAAAAAEMAAAiIsqMbYjsT5e-T7KzowPTAAEMOXaWAAA=",
        "internetMessageHeaders": [
            {
                "name": "Received",
                "value": "from DM6PR15MB2425.namprd15.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:102:2::22) by BYAPR15MB2423.namprd15.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS via CO2PR05CA0054.NAMPRD05.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM; Mon, 10 Sep 2018 21:52:40 +0000"
            },
            {
                "name": "Received",
                "value": "from CO1PR15CA0057.namprd15.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:101:1f::25) by DM6PR15MB2425.namprd15.prod.outlook.com (2603:10b6:5:8e::11) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id 15.20.1122.19; Mon, 10 Sep 2018 21:52:38 +0000"
            },
```

Comment: How are you getting the JSON? Did you use this to get started with Microsoft Graph and Python? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/python

Comment: Yeah, I created the app using the quick start guide, and am just parsing a locally stored JSON file that I got from the Graph Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realized that I didn't need the second for loop.

This worked as expected:

```
for i in range(len(jsonDataList)):
    try:
        headers.append(jsonDataList[i]['internetMessageHeaders'])
    except KeyError:
        continue
    i += 1
```